# gmpxx.h: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, mingw, gmp, mingw32

I just installed a brand new copy of mingw (32 bit) downloading it [from the official project page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) from Sourceforge. I installed everything in the package, all compilers and so on. Then I downloaded from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/gmp/gmp-5.0.1-1/) gmp for MinGW. I extracted gmp-5.0.1-1-mingw32-src.tar.lzma somewhere into my mingw folder, then ran `./pkgbuild` from there. It went on running for some minutes, then printed out something like `COMPLETED EVERYTHING OK, EVERYTHING PASS`.

Then I wrote down this simple example, to check if it was going to work:

```
#include <gmpxx.h>

int main (void)
{
  mpz_class a, b, c;

  a = 1234;
  b = "-5678";
  c = a+b;
  cout << "sum is " << c << "\n";
  cout << "absolute value is " << abs(c) << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

And then compiled it using `g++ mycxxprog.cc -lgmpxx -lgmp`.
The only answer I get is:

```
Fatal error: gmpxx.h: No such file or directory.
```

Does anybody have any hint? I don't really know what should I do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure the is among the directories searched for headers. Find the place where the `gmpxx.h` header resides and add `-I /path/to/header/` on your `g++` line.

Comment: I am facing the same problem here and I don't find the file: I run `sudo find / -iname gmpxx.h` and it returns nothing.  :s

Comment: @VitorLima: Are you sure that you have the necessary packages installed?

Comment: I came back to the gmp's site and I found out that I have to pass the flag *--enable-cxx* to the configure script. So, I recompiled the gmp lib and ran ldconfig. Now, it works fine, I don't need even to use the -I option to compile my programs. (:

Answer (score 17):

`gmpxx.h` header file is included in the `libgmp-dev` package

You can install it on Ubuntu based machines with this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

Comment: The problem is on MinGW, so it's quite useless to tell here what to do on Ubuntu machines...

Comment: So where is it located after running that?

Answer (score 6):

If you are building gmp from source, you need to add the --enable-cxx flag to the configure command.

Answer (score 4):

You can also copy that to the path"/usr/include/", the system will find it.