# Installing sharpSAT on macOS Mojave - "'gmpxx.h' file not found"

Tags: c++, installation, gmp

By following and installing from [sharpSAT](https://github.com/marcthurley/sharpSAT), one's suppose to run the `setupdev.sh` script followed by `make` command. When running `make`, I get 
`'gmpxx.h' file not found` error. I did find a lot regarding error `'gmp.h' not found`, eg. at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375171/pycrypto-install-fatal-error-gmp-h-file-not-found), [here](https://github.com/ethereum/homebrew-ethereum/issues/32) and [here](https://medium.com/software-bugs/fatal-error-gmp-h-file-not-found-84afab886a1e), but these are when installing some other package with either pip or brew.

I've also tried including `usr/local/include` (`gmpxx.h` is located at `usr/local/indluce/gmpxx.h`) to path variable in `.bash_profile` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251070/gmpxx-h-no-such-file-or-directory), but with no good results.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system is having trouble locating the GNU multiprecision libraries.  This answer assumes you used `brew install gmp` to install the multiprecision library.

In sharpSAT's `CMakeLists.txt`, change the line:

`include_directories(/opt/local/include)`

to:

`include_directories("/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/X.Y.Z/include")`

where `X.Y.Z` is your version of `gmp`.  To determine which version of `gmp` you have installed (and in turn where `homebrew` installed gmp), call:

`locate gmp`

You may need to build your location database which can take some time.

You should double check that your system no longer has `/opt/local/include`.