# Undefined reference to `__ms_vsnprintf' when linking GLFW statically

Tags: c++, mingw, glfw, win64

I am trying to compile the GLFW quickstart guide ([Here](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html)) in windows 8 64-bit using mingw. I am using the official 32 bit windows binary from the glfw website.

Everything works fine when I link the glfw library dynamically by linking `-lglfw3dll -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lglew32` and defining `GLFW_DLL`.

When I try to link glfw statically, however, I get `undefined reference to '__ms_vsnprintf'`

My command to link statically is `mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Release\test.exe obj\Release\main.o  -s  -lglfw3 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lglew32s` with `GLEW_STATIC` defined.

Comment: I got past this problem by compiling the GLFW libraries myself. I still don't know why this was happening though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem when I tried to build an example app for GLFW. I switched the compiler suite from original MinGW32 to MinGW-W64 and that solved the problem. I came up with that idea after reading this post:

https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mailman/mingw-users/thread/83ha2x1i7k.fsf%40gnu.org/

Seems the GLFW libs are build with a MinGW64 or MinGW-W64.

Answer (score 1):

`MinGW\include\stdio.h`:

```
/* The following pair ALWAYS refer to the MSVCRT implementations...
 */
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _snprintf (char*, size_t, const char*, ...);
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _vsnprintf (char*, size_t, const char*, __VALIST);
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _vscprintf (const char*, __VALIST);
```

So just use them with underscore in front of them.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered that problem when cross-compiling [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) on Linux for Windos32 with `--host=i686-w64-mingw32`.

As I don't want to mess with GMP's sources or build system, and I have no choice what toolchain to use on Windos32,

> I figured out the following work-around: When linking, link with
>
> ```
> -Wl,-u,___mingw_vsnprintf -Wl,--defsym,___ms_vsnprintf=___mingw_vsnprintf
> ```

I am preferring a C99 compliant version, anyway. Notice that that work-around will drag `___mingw_vsnprintf` no matter what, i.e. even in the case the target code does not use `vsnprintf`.

The mingw version is provided by `libmingwex.a`; you see that gcc links against it with `-Wl,-v` which prints `-lmingwex` (among many others).

The problem might be that the project's configure has some problems figuring out whether the host's `vsnprintf` is working properly or not, or whether the user wants to stick with MS stuff or functions that are C99 compliant.  Anyway, `stdio.h` of my i686-w64-mingw32 cross-tools as well as the `stdio.h` on the host have sections that are secured by

```
#if __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO
/*
 * User has expressed a preference for C99 conformance...
 */
...
#ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
```

and then define `vsnprintf` as a wrapper around a call to  `__mingw_vsnprintf` or around a call to `__ms_vsnprintf`.  Hence there should also be hacks to the build system and inject `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` somewhere.

In the case of autotools, and what worked for me in the case of GMP, is to configure

```
$(srcdir)/configure CPPFLAGS='-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO' ...
```

After re-configure, build and install, `nm libgmp.a | grep vsnprintf` shows for the built libraries

```
         U ___mingw_vsnprintf
```

instead of the previous

```
         U ___ms_vsnprintf
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware this topic is very old, but the solution in my situation was to run `make clean && make` to remove old object files (`.o`) compiled with an incompatible version of GCC.