# undefined reference to __mingw_vfscanf` `undefined reference to __ms_vsnprintf` in opencv3.30

Tags: c++, qt

my platform configure is:

- win10 64bits
- QT5.8 32位(QT Creator 4.21 + MinGW5.30 32bits + Cmake 3.81 64bits)
- Cmake configured as [this blog](https://blog.csdn.net/zbw1185/article/details/82469496)

and I am in trouble that:

```
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibprotobuf.a(strtod.cc.obj): In function `strtod':
D:/Qt/Qt5.8.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/stdlib.h:399: undefined reference to `__mingw_strtod'
D:/Qt/Qt5.8.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/stdlib.h:399: undefined reference to `__mingw_strtod'
../../3rdparty/lib/libzlib.a(gzlib.c.obj): In function `snprintf':
D:/Qt/Qt5.8.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h:557: undefined reference to `__ms_vsnprintf'
../../3rdparty/lib/libzlib.a(gzwrite.c.obj): In function `vsnprintf':
D:/Qt/Qt5.8.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h:545: undefined reference to `__ms_vsnprintf'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibpng.a(pngwrite.c.obj): In function `gmtime':
D:/Qt/Qt5.8.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/time.h:219: undefined reference to `_gmtime32'
../../3rdparty/lib/liblibjasper.a(jas_stream.c.obj): In function `vsnprintf':
D:/Qt/Qt5.8.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h:545: undefined reference to `__ms_vsnprintf'
```

I can not solve `undefined reference to __mingw_vfscanf` and `undefined reference to __ms_vsnprintf`problem. someone say it should be [too chain problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29199720/undefined-reference-to-ms-vsnprintf-when-linking-glfw-statically),but my tool chain is builted in QT except cmake.

Comment: Manually add the mingw libraries, but seems like you should give us the link command cmake generated.

Comment: Thanks, I' vd solved the problem.  There are two MinGW in my computer, and I mixed them up.